# Is a DelayQueue without fairness problematic?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock

In Java 7 the implementation of DelayQueue uses a ReentrantLock without a fairness policy. Is this a problem in the long run? Can a thread starve because of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` (or any other producer/consumer situation), the worker threads are independent and so should be the jobs in the `DelayQueue`. So, no: the order in which threads are allowed to take/poll does not make a difference.